# Foreign key being set as 'null' sometimes in One to Many Relationship, not always

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

Parent Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Library {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id")
private long id;

private String name;


@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JoinColumn(name = "libraryId")
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Child Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id")
private long id;

private String bookName;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JoinColumn (name = "libraryId")
private Library library;

}
```

These are just example classes but I have exactly same relationship and same annotations being used to establish the relationship. There are other data processing which happens in the service class but finally the 'Library' entity is being saved using JPA saveAll() method. No 'Global' variables are being used inside the service class method which is being used to save the entity, so the method is Thread Safe.

Note: Code was being written by somebody else and ideally bi-directional mapping should have been used using mappedBy and joinTable, but this is how it is now.

```
     public void saveLibrary() {

   
    try {

        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setBookName("book1");

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setBookName("book2");


        Library library = new Library();
        library.setName("Library1");
        library.setBooks(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(book1, book2)));

        List<Library> libraries = new ArrayList<>();
        libraries.add(library);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        //other data processing 
        libraryRepository.saveAll(libraries);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

The problem here is that sometimes 'libraryId' (foreign key)remains null.
Most of the time thing works well with valid foreign key. I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: try adding `book1.setLibrary(library)` and `book2.setLibrary(library)` before saving in the repository

Comment: I understand that… but without even setting library reference to book, things work fine most of the times but sometimes it fails.